# Spring - Dynamic loading of config file

Tags: spring

I am writing a spring application in which one config file `common-config.xml` has to be loaded every time and the other config file (product specific config file) has to be loaded dynamically as for loading that config file, I have to first get the product name and then form the config file name.

e.g.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = getApplicationContext(); // returns app ctx initialized at the application startup time

String productName = getProductName();
String version = getProductVersion();
String configFileName = productName + "-" + version + ".xml";

// load the above config file
```

Is it possible in Spring?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "every time" and "loaded dynamically"?

Comment: @Ralph "every time" -> common-config.xml file has to be loaded every time which I am loading at the application startup time. "loaded dynamically" means the second config file has to be loaded by first creating the config file name based on the product name for which this application is running.

Comment: Can the Application context defined in common-config.xml be loaded without the "dynamic" one? (Does it contains all the beans it needs?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your code sample goes in the right direction when it comes to solution of your problem. You could for example calculate the second file name before creating any context at all and then pass it to the constructed context.

Another option is to have two contexts: first one built from common-config.xml and a second one with your dynamically generated file name. The second context would use first one as a parent so it would basically have access to all its beans and settings. Also the second context can be reloaded independently from the first one.